# Define modal view dimensions ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, interface-builder, modalviewcontroller

I am developping a Master-Detail based iApp and I would like a specific button in the Master pane to trigger the apparition of a "settings" Form Window.

I then set my segue as "modal" and I get a form view covering the whole screen. This form comes from the bottom of the screen.

How do I get my view to appear from a slot at the top of the window and to cover, say, 2-thirds of the screen width and 3-quarters of its height?

Thanks!

Comment: iApp ? iPhone or iPad or universal?

Comment: oops. iPad, I thought it was clear as I wrote "Master-Detail" but one indeed can write an iPhone MD iApp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't readily do it using the modal presentation styles, as they are fixed sizes. It is possible to work around but you need to mess around with resizing private views and it quickly starts to feel a bit fragile and messy.

It's simpler to create your own view controller at whatever size you like, add it as a child view controller and animate it into position yourself. You can even add your own background dimming view.

You lose the convenience of segues and the dismissal code, as you're no longer "presenting" the new VC, but that's not hard to recreate.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! do you have some quick'n dirty sample code/example URL to get me started?

Comment: Which part in particular are you having trouble with?

Comment: Typical problems with IB: I drag an UIViewcontroller to the work area and it always appear incredibly huge, compared to the other masks (automatically generated when creating a Master-Detail/CoreData app). Also, I'd be happy to put a small menu bar to the bottom of my MasterView, but it appears after the table, how can I fix it to the bottom?

Comment: In IB you need to change the size to "freeform" then you can make it whatever size you like. I don't use IB very much.

Comment: OK, where do I set that size? IT's not editable in IB's mask (I tried all of the options... may have done something stupid).

Comment: You set freefrom on the view controller, then have to select the main _view_ to set the size. This is sort of the reason I've given up on IB.